# Create a UITextField wherever a user taps on the screen

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield

I am making an iPad app that would be able to recognize where a user taps in a view and creates a UITextField in that location. What is the most efficient way to program this? Will it work for multiple text fields?

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea sounds a little wonky as far as UI goes, but you'd probably want to use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The code would look something like this:

```
// In viewDidLoad
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedInView:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


- (void)tappedInView:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
     CGPoint pointForTextField = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
     // Add the UITextField to your view. You could use the pointForTextField as either the origin or center of the text field
    UITextField *textField = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(pointForTextField.x,pointForTextField.y,100,44)];
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, each time the person tapped you would just add a new textfield.

Comment: Added code to show how you would add a text field. By the way, I strongly recommend this approach over `touchesBegan`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//text field move where you touch in screen
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    point = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",point.x, point.y);
    yourTextField.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, width,height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
   if(locationPoint)
   {
     //add UITextField
     yourTextField.frame = CGRectMake(locationPoint.x, locationPoint.y, 40,40); //change height and width according
   }

}
```